# removing certain data from a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataFrame column where I am looking to remove certain shared information from another pandas Dataframe and produce a dataset that doesn't contain either of the shared data. I have two databases and they each share the same data in some columns. I tried to take the data from one column and say if it doesn't match the data in the other pandas dataFrame, then produce a new dataset without the shared information. For example:

```
               letsee = db7[db7['ISBN'] != 'stop']
```

DB7 contains data that looks like this:

```
        ISBN         retail   discount
      9780060084608   16.99      .4
      9780060520762   23.99      .6
```

and stop contains data that looks like this

```
       ISBN           retail     discount
     9780060084608       15.99     .6
     9780060548780      21.99       .3
```

db7 and stop are two pandas DataFrames. I thought that if the ISBN in db7 doesn't match the database in stop, then it would produce a dataset "letsee" that doesn't contain either of the shared values that are present in both dataFrames. The shared information is still showing up in the letsee dataFrame. How would I make a dataFrame that doesn't contain the shared information present in both DataFrames.

Basically, since the retail and/or discount price has changed from the old file (db7) and the new file (stop) has the new price/discount, I need to remove the information from the original database and have a separate dataset for the information which has changed. The ISBN is used as the identifier that I merged on and combine the two dataFrames. However, I want to have a Dataframe that doesn't contain the shared ISBN. I have tried to update the ISBN information in the original file by replacing the old price with the new price, but I have not been able to (don't know how. So, this step was just to remove the shared ISBN identifer and make a separate file for it.

Both datasets have different ISBN and some shared; I want to identify the shared ISBN and delete them from the entire dataset.

Or another solution would be this: notice that the first row of both dataFrames have the same ISBN. How could I take the stop ISBN information (price and discount) and substitute it and replace it in db7's price and discount? Either that or I have to strip the shared ISBN from the dataFrame and make a separate file for it (which reflects the new retail and discount price).

Comment: Does `db7[db7['ISBN'].str.contains("stop") == False]` work?

Comment: In your example `'stop'` is just a string, but in the text you say that it is another DataFrame - which is it? Can you clarify your question? Did you mean to write `db7['ISBN'] != stop['ISBN']` in the example? Showing the contents of the two data frames (samples) and the desired outcome would help.

Comment: Please add sample of your data

Comment: @GautamChettiar Thank you for your help. The following error message came up: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the two dataframes and then drop duplicates along the `ISBN` column.

```
import pandas as pd
db7 = pd.DataFrame({"ISBN":[9780060084608, 9780060520762], "retail":[16.99, 23.99], "discount": [.4,.6]})
stop = pd.DataFrame({"ISBN":[9780060084608, 9780060548780], "retail":[15.99, 21.99], "discount": [.6,.3]})
print(db7)
print(stop)
```

Output:

```
         ISBN     retail  discount
0  9780060084608   16.99       0.4
1  9780060520762   23.99       0.6
            ISBN  retail  discount
0  9780060084608   15.99       0.6
1  9780060548780   21.99       0.3
```

Now concatenate using `pd.concat` and drop duplicates along the `ISBN` column. Make sure to reset the index.

```
letsee = pd.concat([db7,stop]).drop_duplicates(subset="ISBN", keep=False).reset_index(drop=True)
print(letsee)
```

Output:

```
    ISBN            retail  discount
0   9780060520762   23.99   0.6
1   9780060548780   21.99   0.3
```

Comment: hey thank you it worked! You are appreciated and I am very grateful for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `~isin` ("not is in"). If you have two DataFrames, like this

```py
import pandas as pd

db7 = pd.DataFrame({"ISBN":[123,456,789],"discount":[0.6,0.3,0.4]})
stop = pd.DataFrame({"ISBN":[123,555],"discount":[0.5,0.75]})

print(db7)
print(stop)
```

```
   ISBN  discount
0   123       0.6
1   456       0.3
2   789       0.4
   ISBN  discount
0   123      0.50
1   555      0.75
```

and you want to create a new DataFrame with only ISBN entries from the first one that aren't in the second one, you can do

```py
letsee = db7[~db7["ISBN"].isin(stop["ISBN"])]
print(letsee)
```

which gives the expected result (excluded `123` because it was in `stop`):

```
   ISBN  discount
1   456       0.3
2   789       0.4
```

If you then want to combine this with the `stop` DataFrame you can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```py
merged = pd.concat((letsee, stop), ignore_index=True)
print(merged)
```

which gives you the combination of `db7` and `stop`, and uses the values from `stop` where there were duplicates

```
   ISBN  discount
0   456      0.30
1   789      0.40
2   123      0.50
3   555      0.75
```

Comment: hey thanks it worked! I really appreciate you and thank you for your assistance! You are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
letsee = db7[db7['ISBN'].isin(stop['ISBN'].values)]
```